# Run Function Every Time a Value is Entered or Deleted from a Textarea to Instantly Find Sum

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple JavaScript that solves addition problems (1 + 1 OR 1 + 5 + 2 + 9, etc.). It works fine.

The problem is I want it to continuously run as new values are entered. As soon as I type "1 + 1" it should display 2, if I continue to type and type "+ 1" it should display 3 and so on.

The continuously running part works somewhat. If I enter "1 + 1" the sum is not displayed until I press the spacebar --- but it should immediately display 2 without having to press the spacebar. What am I missing?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z26eg/

HTML

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="addThis"></textarea>
<div id="sum"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementById("addThis");

input.onkeypress = function() {
    var finalAnswer = 0;

    // Get form input
    var processAddThis = addThis.value;

    // Remove all spaces in problem
    // Example problem: 10 +    3   + 2
    processAddThis = processAddThis.replace(/\s/g,''); // 10+3+2

    // Split numbers into an array
    var addTheseValues = processAddThis.split("+");

    // Go through numbers and add them up
    for (var i = 0; i < addTheseValues.length; i++) {
        finalAnswer += Number(addTheseValues[i]);
    }

    // Display sum
    sum.innerHTML = finalAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the function `onkeyup` like the below:

```
input.onkeyup = function() {
    /* The rest of your current code as it already works fine */
};
```

The `keydown` event occurs when the key is pressed, followed immediately by the `keypress` event. During both these times, the value of the key that has been pressed is still not available for calculation.

Then the `keyup` event is generated when the key is released. At this point of time, the value of the key that has been pressed is available for calculation.

In [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/bNKwb/), input any value in the `textarea` and have a look at the console to see the difference between the three events.

Answer (score 3):

You should use on `keyup` instead :

http://jsfiddle.net/z26eg/1/

```
input.onkeyup = function() {
    .....
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the 'onkeyup' event. It works for me.